# Pandas swap values for columns

Tags: python, pandas

What's the simplest way to achieve the below with pandas?

```
df1 = 
       A B C
 0     1 1 2
 1     2 3 1
 2     3 3 2
```

to

```
df_result = 
         1        2     3
 0     [A, B]    [C]    []
 1      [C]      [A]    [B]
 2      []       [C]   [A,B]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame`, aggregate `list` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), lasr remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.stack()
        .reset_index(name='val')
        .groupby(['level_0','val'])['level_1']
        .agg(list)
        .unstack(fill_value=[])
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df)
        1    2       3
0  [A, B]  [C]      []
1     [C]  [A]     [B]
2      []  [C]  [A, B]
```